# Python Cron Job not working

Tags: python, cron

I created following Python script to take screenshots. It takes screenshot, creates directory(s) `2015/09/10` and saves in it as JPG. Now I want to create a cron job to run this script every 5 minutes.

Here's python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import wx
import time
import os
app = wx.App()  # Need to create an App instance before doing anything
screen = wx.ScreenDC()
size = screen.GetSize()
bmp = wx.EmptyBitmap(size[0], size[1])
mem = wx.MemoryDC(bmp)
mem.Blit(0, 0, size[0], size[1], screen, 0, 0)
del mem  # Release bitmap
folder = time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
try:
    os.makedirs(folder)
except OSError:
    if os.path.exists(folder):
        # We are nearly safe
        pass
    else:
        # There was an error on creation, so make sure we know about it
        raise
bmp.SaveFile(folder + '/ScreenShot_'+time.strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S')+'.png', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)
```

Here's the cron job:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/symits/Dropbox/Evernote/Snippets/Python/screenshot.py >/home/symits/log.txt
```

No idea why this cronjob doesn't work. I run the script manually and I get screenshot saved. But Nothing happens via cron. Log.txt file has nothing. 0 Byte.

Comment: Err, your script as shown here doesn't explicitly print anything to stdout, so why should there be anything in the log.txt?

Comment: Where is the folder created when you run it manually? Where is/might it created when it runs as a cron job?

Comment: The folder is created in same directory where the script itself is present.

Comment: Does the folder get created by the cron job?

Comment: No it is not created...

Comment: Your script doesn't appear to force the folder to be created below where the script is - it will be created (or attempted to be) wherever the cwd is. Have you tried forcing the folder to be in a particular path you know is writable? Also, how about actually producing some stdout output to log.txt as early as possible in the script, just to see that the script is in fact running. Or have you tried a simplest-possible 'Hello, World' script just to prove that you can run a cron job at all (irrespective of taking screenshots)?